# How to rollback a apk version in googleplay?

Tags: google-play, publishing

I need to roll back my app to the last version. Is it possible?

I cant not creat a apk from the previous version, cause I dont have the source anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Try to click "Switch to Advanced Mode"

[image]

and then click to "Move Prod"

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: This doesn't work for me and Google Play gives me an error that this is an invalid choice.

Comment: if do you have change a Api level support in new version of app, you don't rollback the apk, the only way is: 1: Rebuild project in its previous state with higher version number (must be higher than all previously submitted versions)
2 : Resubmit

Comment: This answer is out of date

Comment: Not possible for now. Explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192077/619673 or here http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html and search for **Staged Rollouts**

Comment: Please consider getting the question right.. The answer is not relevant