# Upgrade button not displaying in the playStore --android

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I upgraded my app in the play store but my user are seeing the upgrade button. They see open or re-install

The original version was 2.1.4 version code 214.. 
the new version is 3.0.0 version code 84

I see other post that says the version code should be higher and it does not matter that the app version is higher (3.0.0). if that is the case, then how can I republish v3.0.0 with a higher version code?

Please let me know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can rollback from the last updated version. Refer the below link

[Google Play Console - How remove an update of published application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191631/google-play-console-how-remove-an-update-of-published-application)

After rollback take a signed apk with correct version name and version code and publish.